# Changing a portion of a link with Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Do you know the method to change a part of a link in a field in a sql table?

**Example**:

```
mydomain.ltd/image10.png
```

to

```
newdomain.ltd/image10.png
```

This query will delete all the link!

```
UPDATE users SET avatar = 'newdomain' WHERE avatar like '%mydomain%'
```

Comment: Are you just looking for a "find-and-replace" function?  Such that ***all*** occurances of a string get replaced?  Or do you need to be more sophisticated than that?  *(Such as not replacing the string if it's in a file name or some other portion of the URL?)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need `REPLACE` .

Try that:

```
   UPDATE users SET avatar  = REPLACE(avatar, 'www.xxx.com', 'www.yyy.fr')
   WHERE avatar like '%www.xxx.com%'
```

this will replace just the word mydomain to newdomain.

```
  mydomain.ltd/image10.png
```

to

```
  newdomain.ltd/image10.png
```

Comment: Though, as a caveat; that will replace the string `mydomain` in ***every*** occurrence, even where it may not be correct/intended to do so.

Comment: yes since he is using the where clause `WHERE avatar like '%mydomain%'`

Comment: I mean that `http://www.mydomain.org/mydomainshomepage.html` will have the html's file name altered as well, though it's unlikely that would be correct to do so.

Comment: he have this link `mydomain.ltd/image10.png` .

Comment: Start with this:  `http://www.mydomain.org/mydomains_logo.png`  Changing the domain to `stackoverflow` in this way will change ***two*** parts of the url to this...  `http://www.stackoverflow.org/stackoverflows_logo.png`  But changing the .png file's name is likely to be incorrect.

Comment: Thanks you is perfect !
UPDATE users SET avatar  = REPLACE(avatar, 'www.xxx.com', 'www.yyy.fr') WHERE avatar like '%www.xxx.com%'

Comment: @MatBailie then he have to include all link.